# Images won't show up on a gridview from firebase storage

Tags: java, android, url, gridview, firebase-storage

I'm trying to get all the images from a folder inside firebase storage, but this will only load up the cells themselves without a photo.

```java
public void showPictures(View view){
    galleryArrayList.clear();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    String groupCode = this.getArguments().getString("groupNum");
    
    mAuth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(requireActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {

            StorageReference listRef=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(groupCode);
            listRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                    for(StorageReference file:listResult.getItems()){
                        file.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                // adding the url in the arraylist
                                galleryArrayList.add(new PictureClass(uri.toString()));
                            }
                        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                adaptor=new ImageAdaptor(requireContext(),galleryArrayList);
                                gridView.setAdapter(adaptor);
                                gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

[what my app look likes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iMvX.jpg)

[what my storage looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyLXQ.png)